# RStudio, pdflatex fails to knit to pdf and crashes

Tags: pdftex, r, knitr, rstudio

I'm trying to compile a simple `Rnw` file in RStudio using knitr's "compile pdf" functionality. But it gives me an error.

This is what I have in `Vorlage.Rnw`:

```
\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
Running pdflatex.exe on Vorlage.tex...failed
Error running C:/Users/Kris/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 3)
```

I already checked if the `pdflatex.exe` is missing but, it's in the folder exactly where it should be. The package `tinytex` is also already installed but nothing changed.

Here's the information for my operating system from MiKTeX when I start the diagnose:

```
ReportDate: 2021-04-09 11:55:16
CurrentVersion: 21.3
SetupDate: 2021-04-09 11:21:00
SetupVersion: 21.2
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: ab8ebca / 2021-03-19 10:22:46
OS: Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: 2021-04-09 11:21:53
LastUpdate: 2021-04-09 11:22:28
LastUpdateDb: 2021-04-09 11:21:51
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
Root1: C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
Root2: C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserConfig: C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
UserData: C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
```

Any help is greatly appreciated; I am running out of ideas on how to fix this

Comment: To get started, the file you show have not the first  row of any new  empty  file created in Rstudio in R Sweave format: `\documentclass{article}`. LaTeX  is a powerful Turing complete language but still cannot read your mind to guess what kind of document do you want. `:)`